# I've come up with two ways to evaluate $\sum_{1 \le j<k\le n} \frac{k}{k-j}$ but only one of them works

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic

I've come up with two ways to solve this double sum but only one of them works:
$$ \sum_{1 \le j<k\le n} \frac{k}{k-j}$$

---

My first approach is to change $k-j$ into a single $k$. So we have the formula:

$\sum_{k \in K} a_{f(k)} = \sum_{j\in J} a_j.\text{#}f^{-1}(k)$, in which $f:K \rightarrow J$ and $\text{#}f^{-1}(k)$ stands for the number of $k$(s) such that $f(k) = j$

Here are the steps:
$$S = \sum_{1\le j<k\le n} \frac{k}{k-j} = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n} \frac{(k-j)+j}{(k-j)}$$
So here, let $f(k) = k-j$ and because $j$ is a constant in the sum of $k$, appying the above formula, we have:
$$S = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-j} \frac{k+j}{k} = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-j}(1+\frac{j}{k})$$
Now we solve for $$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-j}1\quad\text{ and }\quad\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-j}(\frac{j}{k})$$

By "the law of index exchange":
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-j}(\frac{j}{k}) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-k}(\frac{j}{k}) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}(\sum_{j=1}^{n-k}j) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n^2 +k^2-2nk+n-k}{k} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}[\frac{n(n+1)}{k}+(k-1)-2n] = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} H_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k-1) -n(n-1)$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-j}(1) = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}n - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j$$

Adding them up, we have: $S = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}H_n - \frac{3}{4}n - \frac{n^2}{4}$, which is true for the case of $n=3$ and $n=4$.

There is no $n^3$ but there it is in my second flawed approach:
$$S_2 = \sum_{1\le j<k\le n} \frac{k^2}{k-j} = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n} \frac{k^2}{(k-j)} = \sum_{j=2}^{n}\sum_{k=j+2}^{n+1} \frac{(k-1)^2}{(k-1)-(j-1)}= \sum_{j=2}^{n}\sum_{k=j+2}^{n+1} \frac{k^2 -2k+1}{(k-j)} = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n} \frac{k^2 -2k+1}{(k-j)} + A_{j,k} = S_2 - 2S +S_0 + A_{j,k}\Rightarrow S = \frac{A+S_0}{2}$$, in which: $$S_0 = \sum_{1\le j<k\le n} \frac{1}{k-j} = nH_n - n.$$ We now solve for $A_{j,k}$:
$$A = -\sum_{k=3}^{n+1} \frac{k^2-2k+1}{k-1} + \sum_{k=n+2}^{n+1}\frac{k^2-2k+1}{k-n} - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} j^2 + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{n^2}{n+1-j} = -\sum_{k=3}^{n+1} (k-1) - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} j^2 + n^2\sum_{j=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k}.$$
There's absolutely no way to cancel $n^3$ in $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} j^2$.
I'm a high school student so this is my best. Have i made any stupid mistakes? If so, please point it out for me.

Comment: It is not true that $$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n} \frac{k^2}{(k-j)} = \sum_{j=2}^{n}\sum_{k=j+2}^{n+1} \frac{(k-1)^2}{(k-1)-(j-1)}$$

Comment: Aha! Thank you! Changing k does not alter anything in the formula but j is another story. It should be: $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n} \frac{k^2}{(k-j)} = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+2}^{n+1} \frac{(k-1)^2}{((k-1)-j)} = \sum_{j=2}^{n}\sum_{k=(j-1)+2}^{n+1} \frac{(k-1)^2}{((k-1)-(j-1))}$